# Openlayers page breaks when changing to ES6 import syntax

Tags: jquery, node.js, openlayers, es6-modules, referenceerror

Im building an application with openlayers using node.js and npm to package it. Its a simple one page web map.

Currently my html references an online copy of the ol library, and the javascript file calls classes like this:
`new ol.Map`
But I would like to use import statements and just import the classes I want and then get npm to package it.

As soon as I make the smallest change and simply insert an import statement, then the jquery(?I think?) functionality breaks. I.e. if I insert
`import Map from 'ol/Map.js';`

at the top of my index.js file, then I get the following error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: methodLabel is not defined
    at getAndSetClassesFromData (index.js:212)
    at HTMLInputElement.drawIt (index.js:188)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:5)
    at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:5)
```

Can anyone with more experience point me in the right direction to how to resolve this? I would like to do things the proper way and only import the classes I need.
Thanks from a beginner who is keen to learn but lost!

Comment: Are you sure you have installed npm packages correctly? Or is it work fine before you change the code?

Comment: What is the version of  'ol'?

Comment: Dear Milan, yes it works fine for other applications, and it works fine until I include import statements. ol version 6.1.1

Answer (score 1):

The browser doesn't (yet) understand `import` statements. You will need another tool to **bundle** the required code into a new JS file. This code will read the entire OL library and your code, find and extract every dependencies and bundle them into th new JS file.

You can follow this [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html) that uses Parcel, but other bundlers are available (with more examples [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ol))

Comment: Hi JGH, I did bundle the code with Parcel actually, but the problem remains. If I bundle the code or not, the problem exists. It only breaks when I use an import statement. If I dont, then the code works!

Comment: @staf is the bundle properly created? (i.e does it contains your code + part of the OL lib?) Are you referencing the bundled JS in your page? Have you loaded the OL library via npm?